# Set minimum and max range in relation to window size

Tags: processing

```java
final float MAX_SIZE = 35000;
final float MIN_SIZE = MAX_SIZE/10;
float alienSize;
float alienY;
float alienX;
void draw()
{
    alienX = mouseX;
    alienY = mouseY;
    alienSize = MAX_SIZE*mouseY/height;
}
```

My goal is to make the variable alienSize be the max size when it ( and the mouse ) is at the bottom of the window and 1/10th the size when it ( and the mouse ) is at the top of the window. I have so far this code which works for the max size but there is no limit to how small the alien can get. any help please :)

Edit: I have to hand this in so no cheating please like having an if statement check for the size or anything

Comment: Why would having an `if` statement be cheating?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `map()` function. The `map()` function takes 5 values:

- An input value.
- A minimum input value.
- A maximum input value.
- A minimum output value.
- A maximum output value.

It then returns an output value that's based on the relative position of the input value, scaled to the output min and max. For example, if you call `map(150, 100, 200, 500, 700)` then you'll get back a value of `600` because `150` is halfway between `100` and `200`, so it figures out what value is halfway between `500` and `700`.

Here's an example:

```
float minSize = 50;
float maxSize = 100;

void setup(){
  size(500, 100);
}

void draw(){
  float size = map(mouseX, 0, width, minSize, maxSize);

  background(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, height/2, size, size);
}
```

[image: scaling circle]

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/map_.html).